# new to curl & PHP: how to use it

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am trying to access some basic info from an XML based API. I'm new to this and am getting lost reading the guides on php.net and via google that seem to assume I already know the basics.

The input needs to be formatted as follows:

```
<query>
    <auth_key>xxxxx</auth_key>
    <command>get_account</command>
    <account_id>11122</account_id>
</query>
```

The return will be in an XML format. I assume I need to use CURL to connect and send the input, but I'm lost - how should the PHP code look to do this?

::UPDATE::

okay, I'm still struggling and not making any progress. I've found a tutorial that has kinda lead me to the following code, but it's not doing anything and I can't figure out how/where I'm supposed to acutally send the XML data through to the url.

```
$URL = 'http://www.test.com';
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
    print_r($data);
```

I'm not getting this right and not sure what I'm supposed to be doing. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us the code you've written so far or the parts you are having trouble with? This question is a little too general.

Comment: That's just it, I'm not sure where to start in this one

Comment: Oh I know the feeling. The worst part about not knowing where to start is that it's really difficult to google for the right guide since you don't yet know the vocabulary you should be googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up stumbling on the following link: http://www.phpmind.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-post-xml-using-curl/

From there I got the sample code working and manipulated it to suit my needs. I also ended up using http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php for the xml parsing and it seemed very straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

The API probably expects you to `POST` your request to the server, in which case an [HTTP POST with cURL](http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl) example should help. Check the HTTP code of server response (`200` is good, others are probably bad) - and if it's good then [parse the XML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php).

Most APIs have very good documentation and examples though. It's worth reading through them or Googling for other people in your shoes.

Comment: Unfortunately, this one doesn't have any documentation and I have no way to contact to ask.

Comment: This doesn't really need a lot of documentation on the API. Just do what Tak said, follow the cURL and XML documentation, and you'll get it by trial and error. Of course, this assumes that the API always gives a valid response.

Comment: Agreed! The best way is just to hack at that sample code. I was in the exact same position last year, several pleasant hours of hacking on sample code and away you go!

Comment: I can't get the sample code to work and I don't understand how/where I'm supposed to pass the XML variables across...